# Read backend url from configurable file in ionic

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, ionic3

My backend url in my dev machine is different to that of the production. I want to be able to change the backend url without making changes in the code. I am building for iOS. How do I achieve this ?

Comment: xcconfig will be helpful. Go through this blog https://www.appcoda.com/xcconfig-guide/

Comment: @Abhijit Thanks for comment, but I think the link is for native app development and not applicable to ionic. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I think there is no support for ENV related build but still you can check this thread where many developer had same issue and implemented 3rd party solution on this https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/1205 hope this will helps.

Comment: What do you mean by 'without making changes in the code' ?

Comment: @JuniorGantin Right now I am hardcoding the backend url in the app. If I have to change environments, then I have re-build the app. I want to avoid this re-build every time I change my environment (from dev, test and prod).